# angular calendar directive not rendering in jquery tabs

Tags: fullcalendar, jquery-tabs, angular-ui

Yet another question about the angular calendar directive.  I need to display multiple calendars on one page and am using the jquery tabs widget.  However, only one calendar will render properly.  In normal jquery fullCalendar, you use the 'render' method to ensure that the calendar shows when the tab is selected.  However, this doesn't seem to be working with the angular-ui calendar directive.

Here is a plunker showing what I mean.  Delete the $().tabs() and the three angular calendars display just fine.  Wrap them in tabs, and it no longer works:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HEEX4iqb8kFAsjwdGmkM

Any ideas on why this is not working and how to fix it?

Thanks!

PS.  I will cross-post this question in Google Groups.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that despite the fullCalendar documentation, "show" is not the place to trigger a fullcalendar('render').  I should say, at least not when working with Angular. I don't know if that is correct under normal jQuery usage.  Use the "Activate" event instead:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  activate: function(){
    ("#calendar").fullCalendar('render');
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HEEX4iqb8kFAsjwdGmkM

Comment: Personally I would advocate using `ui-event="active:'whatever()'}`instead. We should probably also add a `ui-refresh` property to the calendar directive too. Feel free to open a bug ticket for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout while rendering.

```
<tab heading="{{tabs[0].title}}" active="tabs[0].active" select="renderCalendar()" disabled="tabs[0].disabled">


     $scope.renderCalendar = function() {
               $timeout(function(){
                    $('.calendar').fullCalendar('render');
                }, 0);
        };
```